# How should one remove duplicate elements in a list where the elements are lists?

Tags: python, list, set, duplicates

I have a list of lists. I want to remove from this list all of the duplicate elements. I have attempted to write a function to do this, but am getting the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` when I try to use it. I think it is something about the compatibility of lists with sets. How should this type of operation be done?

```
def remove_duplicates(x):
    elementsSet = set(x)
    elements = [element for element in elementsSet]
    return elements
```

Comment: Change the list to tuple first so it can be hashed.